# How do you make work from a hardware portfolio accessible (similar to open source software)?

Tags: portfolio, hardware

In software development, one common approach I've seen to creating a portfolio is having a website with your projects and then having a GitHub account (or equivalent) where the actual code can be found. It's nice because everything is in a clean package and the actual product is easy to access.

I know you can have a website for hardware projects, but is there an equivalent to the GitHub solution for hardware? In other words, is there a standard method used by hardware developers to give people access to their hardware products (virtually or not) like software developers do with GitHub? If not, what is the common practice for hardware centric portfolios? Just a website?

Comment: I just have a few videos of each thing. Pictures are fine too.

Comment: Why would you want the inner workings of your hardware on display?

Comment: @Kilisi So people can try it out like someone would when you have code that is open source. Is that not a thing with hardware development?

Comment: Photos, text explanations, videos, and possibly 3D models. I think the location would really depend on which community you're part of. For instance, if you do a lot of Arduino-related work, you may want to see where they post their portfolio on. Github is a safe bet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a good hardware idea you build it and patent. The only people who could understand a blueprint are engineers who could copy your product.

People do put their gadgets on youtube as demonstrations and things like that. But just basic stuff like this [slinging target that took me all of half an hour to build](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knnPkD7AEBc).

Also there are engineering manuals which show a breakdown of parts and wiring diagrams for products which need maintenance. But these are usually heavily patented, you don't create manuals for fun, it's a highly skilled and intensive job.

Comment: Thanks! That's fair. It seems like hardware development is a lot more closed off. With software, you have proprietary code of course, but there is still a really big open source culture. You can find a lot of good software to use or check out that is openly available. I'm just getting started with hardware and the lack of that open source community is different. But anyway, thanks again! Now I know what to do (and not do) with my portfolio as I work on it.